# Javascript denying user input into a field on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, keydown

I have a field with a set number of digits to be allowed. This field has a mask to add commas in the appropriate places.  However if the max number if digits is allowed and the user highlights a comma, they can replace the comma with a digit - then the mask is applied and the field ends up adding extra digits.  I have a function that catches this on keydown and does an e.preventDefault(); when the value length is >= allowedDigits for that field.

The problem is that when the user keys down the number gets placed into the field then it checks it.  Is there any way to remove what the user pressed or check before the input gets placed into the field?

Comment: Please post your code (html and jquery)

Comment: Show us some code, this thing of mask is hard to figure to work. I sugest you to use some masked input already working have many on web. And look each key you'r preventing isn't the comma or something else you want to allow.